# EasyEffects-Pipewire audio choppy when dealing with multiple sources

Tags: arch-linux, pipewire

OS and packages versions:

Arch Linux 6.0.9-arch1-1 kernel

`pipewire --version`
Compiled with libpipewire 0.3.67
Linked with libpipewire 0.3.67

Easy Effects 7.0.1

When I play anything on two different sources(rhytmbox+Firefox seems to be an exception), the audio gets choppy and inaudible (and occasionally high-pitched sine signals?).

I know that when different sources try to play with different audio-samplerates it can cause a mess, so I've tried to set mpv's sample rate to be 48KHz, but it is still choppy.

I've tried disabling one or some effects, but it's still inaudible even with only a single effect.

I thought the problem was F32 and F32P difference. Firefox is using F32, mpv/vlc is using F32P, rhythmbox is using S16. Some steam games use F32 and some S16, and it's still not pointing that the problem is with these formats(?).

The sources that cause these problems have always less than 25ms latency. So is this the problem? Some programs react fast and some slow?

What should I do? Are there any other info required to diagnose this problem?

Edit: Right after I've posted this, easyeffects have crashed and when I restarted it mpv/vlc+firefox does not have this problem. But the games still persist.

[image: Easy Effects Main Menu]
[image: Easy Effects Effects Menu]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing global bitrate and quanta (sample size)??

force everything to 48000 bitrate:

```
pw-metadata -n settings 0 clock.force-rate 48000
```

force everything to 500 sample quanta:

```
pw-metadata -n settings 0 clock.force-quantum 500
```

*500 is quite high latency - you could try something much lower also